# C# / Try-Catch для большого колличества строк кода

Tags: c#, исключения, try-catch

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше обработать исключения, которые могут возникнуть в процессе конвертации? строчек очень много, база спроектирована ужасным образом, могут быть и NULL и вообще что угодно. Каждую строку заключать в try-catch не вариант вообще.

```
        Main.id = Convert.ToInt32(MainData.Rows[0]["id"]);
        Main.date_zv = Convert.ToDateTime(MainData.Rows[0]["date_zv"]);
        Main.flyurograf = Convert.ToDateTime(MainData.Rows[0]["flyurograf"]);
        Main.date_nr = Convert.ToDateTime(MainData.Rows[0]["date_nr"]);
        Main.tel = MainData.Rows[0]["tel"].ToString();
        Main.misce_reg = MainData.Rows[0]["misce_reg"].ToString();
        Main.misce_prog = MainData.Rows[0]["misce_prog"].ToString();
        Main.idenkod = MainData.Rows[0]["idenkod"].ToString();
        Main.ditu = MainData.Rows[0]["ditu"].ToString();
        Main.dekret = MainData.Rows[0]["dekret"].ToString();
        Main.prumitka = MainData.Rows[0]["prumitka"].ToString();
```

Comment: А почему не заключить в try/catch всю конвертацию?

Comment: Какая логика обработки исключения? "Если хотя бы одно поле в строке вызвало исключение -- пропустить всю строку"? Если да - то см. выше комментарий ВладД.

Comment: А связывание через `eval` `bind` вам не подходит? Оно гораздо удобнее

Comment: Класс ридер для Row где будет куча перегруженных методов T TryRead<T>(string name) внутри которых чтение, конвертация и обработка плохого значения. И внешний код останется красивым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй написать функцию которая будет проверять можно ли привести данные к нужному тебе виду(что-то вроде этого):

```
private bool Try(dynamic data, dynamic view)
    {
        //data - то что нужно проверить
        //view - то к чему нужно свести
        try { view(data); }
        catch { return false; }
        return true;
    }
```